# Setup react/zmq on windows

Tags: php, winapi, zeromq, ratchet, reactphp

I am setting up Ratchet on my system following instructions from official site 
I have performed the following:

1. Downloaded and installed zeromq from the official site
2. Followed instructions of http://zeromq.org/bindings:php for PHP bindings and copied the dll files(as the mentioned url is down, I got the dll files from [http://178.79.157.189/~mikko/win32/php-zmq-win32.zip])
   3.Made changes in php.ini file.

But when I restart the server, I get the error:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/5.4.3/ext/php_zmq.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: You need to re-download the zeromq ext. Likely from a different source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [official zeromq PHP binding](http://zeromq.org/bindings%3aphp). I know from experience that it will work.

Download the extension from the [PHP pecl site](http://pecl.php.net/package/zmq). Make sure that you download the right ext for your PHP distro.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the problem was I was using multiple PHP version and there was conflict.